# if we know that the n'th term of a sequence is equal to $\frac{7^n - a^n}{7^n}$, does that imply we have a formula for every $n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

If we know that the n'th term of a sum of a geometric sequence is $\frac{7^n - a^n}{7^n}$ where $a > 0$, does that mean we have a formula for finding any member of the sum of a geometric sequence that n'th term belongs to?

Comment: Why do you have doubts on this. What exactly is it that confuses you?

Comment: Well, because it doesnt follow the standard pattern of a sum of a geometric sequence so I was confued if that formula implies that the n-2'th term could be found by that same formula

Comment: A geometric sequence has the same constant ratio between each term of the sequence. The sequence you have given above does not have the same ratio between each term. Therefore your sequence is not a geometric sequence.

Comment: Ok, sorry it's actually supposed to be the sum Sn of a geometric sequence's first n terms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if I have understood your question correctly, you are given that the sum of the first $n$ terms of a geometric sequence is given by:$$S_n=\frac{7^n-a^n}{7^n}=1-\left(\frac{a}{7}\right)^n$$This means that:$$S_1=1-\frac{a}{7}=t_1\tag{1}$$where $t_1$ is the first term of the sequence. Similarly:$$S_2=1-\left(\frac{a}{7}\right)^2=\left(1-\frac{a}{7}\right)\left(1+\frac{a}{7}\right)$$$$\therefore S_2=1-\frac{a}{7}+\frac{a}{7}\left(1-\frac{a}{7}\right)=t_1+\frac{a}{7}\left(1-\frac{a}{7}\right)=t_1+t_2\tag{2}$$$$\therefore t_2=\frac{a}{7}\left(1-\frac{a}{7}\right)=\frac{a}{7}\times t_1$$You therefore have a geometric sequence where the first term is $1-\frac{a}{7}$ and the common ratio is $\frac{a}{7}$.

If you use these in the standard formula for the sum of a geometric sequence then you should end up with the expression in your question.